# How to use CURL tool?

Tags: command-line, http, curl

I just got introduced to CURL today and I went to their website to download the tool and all I got is .cgi file called "metalink" and I don't know how to use it or how to run it, can someone help please what is the step zero where I can at least try the example commands on their website? I don't even know how the interface of CURL looks like but I'm assuming a black screen since it's a "command line tool".
Thanks

Comment: You seem to have found the wrong web-site: it is NOT curl.com.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before asking a question, please do a minimal amount of research. `curl.com` is not the website for cURL. In fact, it is https://curl.haxx.se/.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Wikipedia and the [man pages](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for specific question on what to do with cURL.

I'm assuming you're using Windows (please provide this information next time), so I recommend [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html). Just download the installer, install it, and run the cygwin application (there you will get your "command line"). Then you can use the cygwin package manager to install curl.

If you however prefer just the executable cURL you downloaded the wrong file. Download the zip file for windows from their homepage curl.haxx.se, unpack it, then open a command line ("Windows+R") and change to the directory where you unpacked it. You can run the executable there.